# What does $config['disable_all_tracking'] do?

Tags: config, config-overrides

Not sure how to choose to set $env_config['disable_all_tracking'] = 'y' or 'no'; When documentation says if set to 'y' some of the below settings are disregarded

```
/* Tracking
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$env_config['disable_all_tracking']        = 'y'; // If set to 'y' some of the below settings are disregarded
$env_config['enable_sql_caching']          = 'n';
$env_config['disable_tag_caching']         = 'n';
$env_config['enable_online_user_tracking'] = 'n';
$env_config['dynamic_tracking_disabling']  = '500';
$env_config['enable_hit_tracking']         = 'n';
$env_config['enable_entry_view_tracking']  = 'n';
$env_config['log_referrers']               = 'n';
$env_config['gzip_output']                 = 'y';
```

Thanks in advance for great support

Comment: Hi Dorothy ... What is the question exactly? Can you clarify?

Comment: The default in this published masterconfig is  $env_config['disable_all_tracking']  = 'y';

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm still not certain what your overall question is, but I can explain **$env_config['disable_all_tracking'] = 'y';**.

```
$env_config['disable_all_tracking']        = 'y';
```

Is part of ExpressionEngine's option for [Handling Extreme Traffic](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/handling_extreme_traffic.html). If you `disable_all_tracking` then you **do not** have to individually set the options for:

```
$env_config['enable_online_user_tracking'] = 'n';
$env_config['dynamic_tracking_disabling']  = '500';
$env_config['enable_hit_tracking']         = 'n';
$env_config['enable_entry_view_tracking']  = 'n';
$env_config['log_referrers']               = 'n';
```

These `disable_all_tracking` option is generally set to 'n', but if your basing it off a master config that is trying to maximize performance, then it would be set to yes.

These options are best used for **traffic spikes** or sites that are constantly hit heavily. For your average site, having tracking on is fine, and will provide you with a variety of information that can be used to help you measure the site's success.

But, many of these details are also provided by [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) (GA) and content delivery networks (CDN), such as [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com). So as long as your site is configured to use an analytics program, those details are still available to you, just not via the control panel.

Some developers leave this variables on by default, and I know others turn them off by default, so that is up to you for the site your building or managing.

Also if you need to deal with heavy traffic sites or just want to make a site that performs better, add Solspace's [Website Performance Guidelines](http://www.solspace.com/downloads/PerformanceGuidelines.pdf) to your reading list, and take a look at some of their [performance enhancing](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/static_page_caching/) add-ons. You can also take a look at Matt Perry's [Make EE Faster](http://mattoperry.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/ee-scaling.pdf) presentation.

Comment: I'm using GA and Cloudflare.  Fantastic explanation.  I definitely need to set disable_all_tracking option to "n"

Comment: Just to make sure, the 'no' keeps tracking on, and the 'yes' turns it off. It's just that you used the word 'definitely', which made me think you had a high traffic site, but then you said, set to 'no'.

Comment: Followed your advice and site is so fast as a result it's smoking.  Thanks.